# free(): invalid pointer error on vector.push_back()

Tags: c++

My code gives me `free(): invalid pointer` error (I don't call `free`, so my understanding is that it has something to do with how `vector`s operate internally). I am beginner to C++, so though I checked other answers to similar questions, I fail to see what exactly causes the issue.

I have a grid graph (i.e. vertex is connected with its 4-neighbors). Some vertices hold a special value, which is written done in a file in a form:

```
row columns value
```

The code:

```
graph::graph(const char *file_name) {
    ifstream infile(file_name);
    istringstream iss;

    int R = 2; // number of rows
    int C = 4; // number of columns
    for (int i=0; i<R*C; i++) add_vertex(i+1);

    adj = new std::vector<edge*>[R*C]; // adjacency list

    // add all edges to the grid
    for (int r=0; r<R; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<C; c++) {
            if (c!=C-1) add_edge(vertices[r*C+c], vertices[r*C+(c+1)]);
            if (r!=R-1) add_edge(vertices[r*C+c], vertices[(r+1)*C+c]);
        }
    }

    int P = 2; // number of vertices holding a special value
    for (int i=0; i<P; i++) {
        getline(infile, line);
        iss.str(line);
        iss >> r >> c >> p;
        vertices[r*C+c]->set_value(p);
        p_vertices.push_back(vertices[r*C+c]);
        iss.clear();
    }

    void graph::add_vertex(int v) {
        auto *vert = new vertex(v);
        vertices.push_back(vert);
    }

    void graph::add_edge(vertex *v, vertex *u) {
        edge e = std::make_tuple(v, u, 1);
        adj[v->get_id()].push_back(&e);
        adj[u->get_id()].push_back(&e);
    }
```

Header:

```
#include "vertex.h"

typedef std::tuple<vertex*, vertex*, int> edge;

class graph {
private:
    std::vector<vertex*> vertices; // all vertices
    std::vector<vertex*> p_vertices; // vertices with a special value
    std::vector<edge*> *adj; // adjacency list

public:
    explicit graph(const char *file_name);
    void add_vertex(int v);
    void add_edge(vertex *v, vertex *u);
};
```

Header for a vertex:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class vertex {
private:
    int id;
    int val;

public:
    explicit vertex(int id) {
        this->id = id;
        this->val = 0;
    };
    int get_id() { return id; };
    void set_value(int p) { val = p; };
};
```

Example input:

```
0 0 1
1 2 3
```

The error disappears if I comment out this line:

```
p_vertices.push_back(vertices[r*C+c]);
```

And remains even if I try to change `p_vertices` to `std::vector<int>` instead of `std::vector<vertex*>` (and use `p_vertices.push_back(r*C+c)`).

Thanks for any hints on how to fix the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Try to remove reading input and files. Insert all necessary data into your example.

Comment: Are you sure that `vertices[r*C+c]` is valid? Try to change all calls to `vertices.at(r*C+c)` (and others) and check if exceptions are thrown.

Comment: `adj = new std::vector<edge*>[R*C];` ... my eyes hurt. Where's this destroyed?

Comment: This line is very strange to me: `adj = new std::vector<edge*>[R*C]; // adjacency list`
Is there any reason you need to allocate the vector dynamically? I don't think so. In your `graph` class you should store a simple `std::vector<edge*> adj` which is not a pointer.

Also if you want toprovide a starting size you should use simple brackets and not square brackets like this: `adj = std::vector<edge*>(R*C); // adjacency list`
I think your problem might be this if you use this list in any of your functions

Comment: @johnyka It's an array of vectors. (Which should really be `std::vector<std::vector<edge*>>`.)

Comment: Another likely culprit is `add_vertex`.

Comment: Added `add_vertex` and `add_edge`, I accidentally "lost" it when I was writing the original question.

Comment: @molbdnilo should it really be a vector of vectors (i.e. proposed `std::vector<std::vector<edge*>>`) instead of an array of vectors if the number of vertices is known at the object creation and will not be changed? I thought the whole point to use a vector instead of an array is to allow dynamical increase of the size.

Comment: @Valeria I was assuming that there would come a time when `R` and `C` would not be hard-coded. If they always are 2 and 4, I would  just use a 2D array.

Comment: @molbdnilo they can be arbitrarily large but always defined only once for each run of a program.

Comment: You can use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain arrays.

Comment: @asynts and what about inner vector of pointers to tuples (to `edge`) itself? I finally noticed that edge `e = std::make_tuple(v, u, 1);`  always create a tuple on the same address at each call of `graph:add_edge`, which makes adjacency matrix `adj` clearly wrong. Should it be instead vector of tuples, or what would be correct way to treat it in C++?

Comment: It depends on where you are going with this. The `new_vertex` function suggests that you want to dynamically add vertices (which won't work since `adj` must be expanded too) but at the moment you simply have a constant somewhere that determines the size of the array.

I think you really want a different data structure, where each vertex 'owns' the adjacents ([Example](https://godbolt.org/z/wX0gjG)). If you know the amount of vertices and edges beforehand, then simply replace `std::vector` with `std::array`.